# Firefox addon which refreshes the tap and auto resend data

Tags: post, firefox-addon, reload, firefox-addon-sdk, page-refresh

I'm trying make a firefox add-on, which reloads a page automatically under some conditions.

First I add a contentScript to a tab to get some information on the page in my addon

```
tab.attach({
            contentScript:self.port.emit...
```

I have it working to the point of the refresh with

```
tab.reload();
```

but then an alert pops up every time "if it should resend data".

I want to resend the data automatically.
How and where do I do it? In the add-on or in the contentScript?
Has it to do with the Load Flags constant?

Comment: Can you copy paste exactly what the prompt says, i cant get that popup to show but once i do i have text of it i can dig around for it on mxr.

Comment: not sure if it helps cause it is german: "Um diese Seite anzuzeigen, müssen die von Firefox gesendeten Daten erneut gesendet werden, wodurch alle zuvor durchgeführten Aktionen wiederholt werden (wie eine Suche oder eine Bestellungsaufgabe)." and I can click "erneut senden" and "abbrechen"

Comment: That helps thanks Ok so this stuff is called from this cpp file: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/docshell/base/nsDocShell.cpp#12058 so we have to look for something here so at first glance if you bit wise the LOAD_CMD_RELOAD flag out of the loadType it wont msg that but it will screw up other stuff so we dont want to do that.

Comment: thanks for the help/reply, but I don't really get what you are saying! What should or shouldn't I do?

Comment: We sitll have to research i havent found a way yet, posted the mxr link so maybe others can help out too, im a bit busy

Comment: oh ok thanks. I found this link which looks kind of like it is talking about the same [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/netscape.public.mozilla.wishlist/OIVvc0zmvlg/kS8HGlIPibQJ) but the issue there is, that it turns the "confirm popup" off.

Comment: oh and an other thing I thought off. Would it be a possibility to "just click" the confirm out of the ff addon? I also wouldn't know how to do that. (I only found how to make a popup not how to manipulate it [window.confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm))

Comment: Great idea! I think its MUCH easier to auto click ok i didnt think of that. We would use window watcher http://stackoverflow.com/a/27279211/1828637 and watch for the confirm window. try it out from the topic i just linked

Answer (score 2):

This clicks the accept button when the prompt opens. But you see the prompt window for like a couple hundred ms.

i had to use `setTimeout` with 0 wait time other wise the `aDOMWindow.args` property and `aDOMWindow.Dialog` and a bunch of other stuff would be undefined or null so weird. But this works:

```
var stringBundle = Services.strings.createBundle('chrome://browser/locale/appstrings.properties');

try {
    windowListener.unregister();
} catch (ignore) {}

var windowListener = {
    //DO NOT EDIT HERE
    onOpenWindow: function(aXULWindow) {
        // Wait for the window to finish loading
        let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
        aDOMWindow.addEventListener('load', function() {
            aDOMWindow.removeEventListener('load', arguments.callee, false);
            windowListener.loadIntoWindow(aDOMWindow, aXULWindow);
        }, false);
    },
    onCloseWindow: function(aXULWindow) {},
    onWindowTitleChange: function(aXULWindow, aNewTitle) {},
    register: function() {
        // Load into any existing windows
        let XULWindows = Services.wm.getXULWindowEnumerator(null);
        while (XULWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
            let aXULWindow = XULWindows.getNext();
            let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
            windowListener.loadIntoWindow(aDOMWindow, aXULWindow);
        }
        // Listen to new windows
        Services.wm.addListener(windowListener);
    },
    unregister: function() {
        // Unload from any existing windows
        let XULWindows = Services.wm.getXULWindowEnumerator(null);
        while (XULWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
            let aXULWindow = XULWindows.getNext();
            let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
            windowListener.unloadFromWindow(aDOMWindow, aXULWindow);
        }
        //Stop listening so future added windows dont get this attached
        Services.wm.removeListener(windowListener);
    },
    //END - DO NOT EDIT HERE
    loadIntoWindow: function(aDOMWindow, aXULWindow) {
        if (!aDOMWindow) {
            return;
        }
        if (aDOMWindow.location == 'chrome://global/content/commonDialog.xul') {
            var repostString = stringBundle.GetStringFromName('confirmRepostPrompt');
            var repostStringFormatted = stringBundle.formatStringFromName('confirmRepostPrompt', [aDOMWindow.Application.name], 1);
            aDOMWindow.setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('setimeout val 00:', aDOMWindow.args)
                    //aDOMWindow.args and aDOMWindow.Dialog is not available till after setTimeout of 0 so weird
                if (aDOMWindow.args.text == repostString || aDOMWindow.args.text == repostStringFormatted) {
                    console.log('this is resend prompt so accept it');
                    //aDOMWindow.Dialog.ui.button0.click(); //doesnt work
                    //aDOMWindow.Dialog.onButton0(); // doesnt work
                    //aDOMWindow.ondialogaccept(); //doesnt work
                    var dialog = aDOMWindow.document.getElementById('commonDialog');
                    var btnAccept = aDOMWindow.document.getAnonymousElementByAttribute(dialog, 'dlgtype', 'accept');
                    btnAccept.click();
                    console.log('clicked');
                }
            }, 0);
        }

    },
    unloadFromWindow: function(aDOMWindow, aXULWindow) {
        if (!aDOMWindow) {
            return;
        }
    }
};

windowListener.register();
```

open scratchpad. set environemnt to browser. run the code. refresh a page to get prompt you'll see it get clicked.