# Catch popup window and notify user in Firefox

Tags: javascript, popup, firefox-addon, popupwindow, dom-events

There is a web site that randomly shows up some campaign popup windows on their web site. It would be very useful if a user would be notified when a popup is shown up on that site in Firefox, etc. Can it be possible with the help of Javascript, or any add-on, etc.?

Comment: Can you please provide more info like how pop ups windows are shown. I guess if you are using any plug in eg Jquery UI plugin , then you can use those events to notify user.

Comment: The popup window appears randomly when refreshing the page. I know there are some plugins refreshing web browsers. But I need to be notified or catch when a popup appears on a browser tab. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two options.

nsIWindowWatcher - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowWatcher

nsiWindowMediator - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWindowMediator

This is the nsiwindowmediator way:

```
/*start - windowlistener*/
var windowListener = {
    onOpenWindow: function (aXULWindow) {
        // Wait for the window to finish loading
        let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
        aDOMWindow.addEventListener('load', function () {
            aDOMWindow.removeEventListener('load', arguments.callee, false);
            //window loaded, now the website will load so addeventlistener for that
            //check what the website loading is here, if its your campain thing then block it
        }, false);
    },
    onCloseWindow: function (aXULWindow) {},
    onWindowTitleChange: function (aXULWindow, aNewTitle) {},
};
/*end - windowlistener*/

Services.wm.addListener(windowListener);
//Services.wm.removeListener(windowListener);
```

so now in the onOpenWindow, you can see what is the window opener, if it was that website, then close that window.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and good explanation. However I could not apply this code due to not knowing which on which way to go. In addition to this there is no field to enter website that I listen. Do you mean to write mozilla plugin? Could you please clarify me a little bit more or give a demo with this solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes this is firefox-addon code. Firefox has a built in popup blocker though thats a good thing to use.

Comment: So, is it hard to be learnt by a Java or .Net programmer? I just need such a kind of mozilla plugin in order to needing this add-on.

Comment: No its piece of cake. Try looking into firefox-addon-sdk thats even easier.