# Suppress confirm window in the firefox

Tags: firefox, window, firefox-addon, confirm

Is there are any way to do this? Addons or auto submit or in some other way?
Was such addons AlertStopper, but now don't work.

Comment: Someone asked this question in the past, I gave them one solution of listening to the alert window opening, and then automatically clicking "OK". Here is the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259603/firefox-addon-which-refreshes-the-tap-and-auto-resend-data/27338180#27338180